# Xenomai - can't open device

Tags: c, driver, posix, device, xenomai

I write an user space application.When I run `fd = rt_dev_open("/dev/ttyACM0");`, I get an error. It says that `no such device`. But when I use POSIX open() functions, it works fine. How can I use this file xenoami rtdm module?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I just edited question.

Answer (score -1):

To run functions real time, we need a rtdm driver. If we don't have, we can't use functions of real time.

Comment: isn't rt_dev_open funcion already in rtdm library linked? what do you mean by rtdm driver? how did you manage to enable it?